# python inspect getsource gives OSError: source code not available

Tags: python

I am trying to get the source code for the python library zlib, however when I run the following:

```
import zlib
x=inspect.getsource(zlib)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 1024, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 1006, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 827, in findsource
    raise OSError('source code not available')
OSError: source code not available
```

What does this mean exactly? Clearly there is some kind of code somewhere on my computer. Where is this code?

Comment: No, there isn't necessarily any source code on your computer. There may only be, say, a compiled C binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is probably a compiled c binary and not python source code, so it is not showing up in `inspect.getsource`

Comment: Is there a way for me to access this C code?

Comment: You can access it, but it would look like gibberish as it is compiled

Comment: I don’t think you can access the actual C code

Comment: You can convert the compiled source to assembly code though, if you want to